# What does the "imageSizes" configuration option for Nextjs optimized Image component actually do?

Tags: next.js

I have been using Next.js new optimized Image component, and I think I understand how it works when using the different layout options (`intrinsic`, `fixed`, `responsive` and `fill`). However there is a configuration option called `imageSizes` that I don't understand.

From the docs, I can tell there are these two default configuration options:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    deviceSizes: [640, 750, 828, 1080, 1200, 1920, 2048, 3840],
    imageSizes: [16, 32, 48, 64, 96, 128, 256, 384],
  },
}
```

If I understand correctly, `devicesSizes` is an array of breakpoints of sorts; when using the `fill` or `responsive` layout for an image, Nextjs creates multiple versions of the image whose widths correspond to the breakpoints, and references those versions in the `srcset` that it automatically generates for that image. We may also tell the browser how to use these versions via the `sizes` prop. For example:

```
<Image 
    image={ image }
    layout="responsive" 
    sizes="(max-width: 500px) 100vw, 25vw" 
    width={1200}
    height={960}
/>
```

For `imageSizes`, the docs say that:

> You can specify a list of image widths using the imageSizes property.
> These widths should be different (usually smaller) than the widths
> defined in deviceSizes because the arrays will be concatenated. These
> widths are used when the next/image component uses layout="fixed" or
> layout="intrinsic".

Does this mean that, when using a `fixed` or `intrinsic` layout, Nextjs creates multiple versions of the image whose widths correspond to the values in `imageSizes`? If so, how can you tell the `<Image />` component which one to use (since the docs also say that the `size` prop should be used with the `fill` and `responsive` layouts only)?

In other words, if I have an image that is 1200px wide and I want to use it at one of the sizes specified in `imageSizes`, how do I do that?

Comment: Relevant GitHub discussion: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/24771.

Answer (score 2):

### You don't choose.

##### The algorithm will choose it for you based on the scenario...

The first thing that you have to realize is that one group (deviceSizes) is for large images and two layouts: fill and responsive:
The other is for small images (imageSizes) and the last two layouts: fixed and instrisic.

Let's run some test, and see the results:

Next config:

```
images: {
    deviceSizes: [640, 750, 828, 1080, 1200],
    imageSizes:  [32,  64,  96,  128,   256],
}
```

Component config:

```js
const ImageUse = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ position: 'relative', display: 'block', width: '1100px', height: "766px" }}>
        <Image layout="fill" src="/assets/image_1.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div style={{ position: 'relative', display: 'block', width: '100%', height: "auto" }}>
        <Image
          layout="responsive"
          src="/assets/image_2.jpg"
          width="700"
          height="560"
        />
      </div>
      <div style={{ position: 'relative', display: 'block', width: '200px', height: "160px" }}>
        <Image
          layout="fixed"
          src="/assets/image_3.jpg"
          width="180"
          height="64"
        />
      </div>
      <div style={{ position: 'relative', display: 'block', width: '100px', height: "72px" }}>
        <Image
          layout="intrinsic"
          src="/assets/image_4.jpg"
          width="96"
          height="60"
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

This is the result:

```
originImage: 1475w x 1180h (jpg)

viewport:    1100w
1 and 2: 1200w x 960h 
3 and 4: 250w x 205h

viewport:    900w
1 and 2: 1080w x 864h 
3: 256w x 205h
4: 96w x 77h

viewport:    700w
1 and 2: 640w x 512h 
3: 256w x 205h
4: 96w x 77h
```

Do you see? Based on the range that the image fall with the correspondent config, you get a different result.

It's not quite easy to guess which choice it's going to be. The 900w viewport got and 1080w image (the choice above viewport size). The 700 had a smaller image than the viewport.

**You don't precisely choose the image, but that doesn't mean that you don't have a lot of control.**

Credits to `@bobarros` that answer this on Github: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/24771